# Copy rows from same table with new primary key and specific foreign key

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables **session** and **class** relating class with session by **sessionid** 
I want to copy **classnames** to the same classes table with new **classid** and with the new **foreign key** which is 2 in session table.

classes   ' table name

```
 sessionid    classid    class   
1               1         5th
1               2         6th
1               3         7th
```

and the session table is

```
sessionid    session
1            2013-2014
2            2014-2015
```

want to copy to session 2014-2015

hope you understand

```
Insert Into classes (sessionid,classname) Values ((select sessionid from session where session=@session),classname)
```

this is what I cud do.

Comment: please, please, please elaborate on what you are asking.

Comment: now what have you tried?  please read through [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Insert Into classes (sessionid,classname) Values
((select sessionid from session where session=@session),classname)

this is what I cud do.

Comment: please add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Insert Into classes (sessionid,classname) 
Values (SELECT 2, classname 
         FROM classes
         WHERE sessionid = 1)
```

I have not tested this, I am sure that I might find some issues with this, so please if someone sees an issue with my Code please comment and I will fix it.

**UPDATE**

I may have changed the Column Names, so if all you did was copy and paste, your column names may not have matched.  and @Fauzi88 commented that I didn't need to use `VALUES` in the query.

hopefully this helps

I ran the following Query and it performed on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/274a9/1/0)

```
INSERT INTO classes (sessionid,class)
SELECT 2, class 
FROM classes
WHERE sessionid = 1
```

**you might want to try this one instead of the previous one**

the logic is the same.

Comment: SQLFiddle.com won't let me do SQL Server code and the MySQL won't let me insert into the table like that.  but the select statement works

Comment: Insert table from select statement, don't use "values"

Comment: what I have seen you can't do a `SELECT INTO` on an Existing table